# WMS WMTS TMS Server Stress Tool

Tags: web-mapping, web-service

Someone knows about a tool that test the cpu usage, memory, IO Read/Write with MapProxy or a WMS, WMTS, TMS Server?

Like a 'Web Stress tool' that test Server with concurrent clients request and navigation through the site.

Comment: jmeter - http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: thanks! Can I use it with IIS, Nginx too, right?

Comment: jmeter does replays that can be recorded using different ways so yes you can use it with any server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also can recommend JMeter, as iant already mentioned. Its very flexible and after a while simple to use.

If you look for something more "eye candy" like you can also try loadUI (http://www.loadui.org/) which is a little bit more intuitive. Its not as flexible as Jmeter, but in my opinion its a more lightweight load testing tool which you can also use for monitoring purposes.

Comment: [http://www.loadui.org/](http://www.loadui.org/) aparently is broken...(maybe is my connection)
thanks for the answer, I try JMeter first.

Comment: What about **pylot**?
[pylot.org](http://pylot.org/)